# Forward declaration syntaxes have different behavior

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

When forward declaring the member of a class, you can either do `class Bar; Bar* m_bar`or the shorter `class Bar* m_bar`. But the name resolution seems to behave differently.

For example this compiles perfectly:

```
struct Foo {
  Foo();
  struct Bar;
  Bar* m_bar;
  struct Bar {
      int m_baz;
  };
};

Foo::Foo(){
    m_bar = new Foo::Bar;
}
```

While this doesn't, because the compiler thinks the type of `m_bar`is not `Foo::Bar` but just `Bar` :

```
struct Foo {
  Foo();
  struct Bar* m_bar;
  struct Bar {
      int m_baz;
  };
};

Foo::Foo(){
    m_bar = new Foo::Bar;
}
```

My question is more out of curiosity than an actual problem (and I know forward declaration and nested classes are a touchy subject in C++), but why does the compiler interprets the second version as a global name ?

Comment: My gut feeling is that `struct Bar * m_bar;` does not add `struct Bar` to the *class definition*. It just says, "hey, there's some ambient class called `Bar`." The first version, though, first adds the nested class declaration to the class definition of `Foo`, and then `Bar *` refers to *that* nested class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spec says this in 3.3.2p6bullet2 (it actually just says into what scope the name declared is added to. If I remember correctly, there is no explicit rule that says that the class is a member of that namespace).

I think that this is an important C compatibility feature. If it wasn't this way, the class would be global in C, but a class member in C++.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the standard :). It seems that, if I understand correctly, when you declare `struct Bar* m_bar`,
"the identifier is declared in the smallest
non-class, non-function-prototype scope that contains the declaration". 
(3.3.1.5), so it's explicitely outside any class scope.